# Object reference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

I have a situation programming for the iPhone.  I have an Object (object A) that contains another Object (object B). Is there a way to reference object A from Object B? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: Could this question title be worded better? This was exactly what I was looking for, but the title made it hard to find. I don't have enough rep (I think?) to edit other's questions - or is that a mod power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the classes reference each other like this:

**ClassA.h:**

```
@class ClassB // let the compiler know that there is a class named "ClassB"

@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    ClassB *objectB;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ClassB *objectB;

@end
```

**ClassB.h:**

```
@class ClassA; // let the compiler know that there is a class named "ClassA"

@interface ClassB : NSObject {
    ClassA *objectA;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) ClassA *objectA; // "child" object should not retain its "parent"

@end
```

**ClassA.m:**

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize objectB;

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        objectB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
        objectB.objectA = self;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

**ClassB.m:**

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassB.h"

@implementation ClassB;

@synthesize objectA;

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // no need to set objectA here
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: That worked - thank you. One issue is that the line @class directive should have a semicolon, such as `@class ClassA;`

Comment: +1, except I would make B's A property `assign` and not `retain`, just to avoid a retain cycle.

Comment: Changed objectA property (in ClassB) to "assign".

Answer (score 3):

No.  Object B needs to have its own pointer to Object A.